# Setting up Webpack to change the URL path for CSS background-img

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I'm using [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and in my CSS I reference background-image like so:

```
background-image: url("/images/icons/checkDark.svg");
```

It works fine when I run the project locally as my folder structure is like this:

> rootDirectory/public/images/icons/checkDark.svg

Now when I *build* the application.. the folder structure ends up like this:

> buildFolder/images/icons/checkDark.svg

When I *deploy* the application as-is, the icon doesn't load because the build structure is different from my project structure.

Is there a webpack setting I can change so that the urls turn out like this?

```
background-image: url("../../images/icons/checkDark.svg");
```

Note: I added the "../.." in front.

Comment: Why not just use relative path in `background-image` rule?

Comment: @chenxsan i tried using "./" but for some reason the path comes from where the CSS file is located rather than the root url.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `./` in css would resolve the image right from where the css file is located, and that's how it works. Without a reproducible repository I can't help you as I'm not familiar with this redux toolkit.

Comment: @chenxsan hey thanks for responding. maybe i can just try to explain better.  No matter what path I use, it seems to come from where the css file is located... so the only thing that works is if i put the "../../" in front of the url because that's where it's located in the build.. but my local project files do not match the folder structure of the build structure when i run "npm run build" so putting "../../" doesn't work if i run it locally.. so I'm not really sure waht to do.